# Error conexion.open c#

Tags: c#, sql

Estoy aprendiendo a programar y quiero añadir una funcionalidad de inserción a una base de datos en un botón, he intentado lo siguiente:

```
string query = "INSERT INTO Producto (Nombre,Precio) 
VALUES (@nombre,@precio)";
conexion.Open();
```

Pero no me reconoce la conexion. ¿Donde puede estar mi error? Gracias.

Comment: Te falta instanciar la clase de la conexion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suponiendo que la base de datos es de SQLServer:

> 1. Para insertar en la base de datos lo primero que debes hacer es definir la conexión en una variable global (si quieres reutilizarla en distintos métodos). Puedes realizarla mediante la interfaz gráfica desde:
>
> Explorador de soluciones> Botón derecho del ratón encima del proyecto> Propiedades> Configuración> variable de tipo cadena de conexión
>
> O bien asignarla mediante código:

```
 public string cn = "Data Source=miservidor\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=tubasededatos;User ID=tuusuario;Password=tupassword";
```

> 2. Después deberás definir e instanciar en la función de tu botón lo siguiente:

```
 string query = "INSERT INTO Producto (Nombre,Precio) VALUES (@nombre,@precio)"; //tu query

 SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(cn); // tu conexión pasando el string con la ruta a la conexión

 conexion.Open(); //abres tu conexión

 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn); //ejecutas tu query en la conexión

 cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int); //Añades el parámetro id
 cmd.Parameters["@id"].Value = int.Parse(textBoxID.Text); //le asignas el valor al parámetro parseandolo a id suponiendo que lo extraes de un textBox y que el campo int es integer

 cmd.Parameters.Add("@precio", SqlDbType.Int); //Añades el parámetro precio
 cmd.Parameters["@precio"].Value = int.Parse(textBoxPrecio.Text); //le asignas el valor al parámetro parseandolo a int suponiendo que lo extraes de un textBox y que el campo precio es integer

 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();//ejecutas el comando

 cn.Close(); //cierras tu conexión
```